# Object Info node random output doesn't work properly

Tags: rendering, materials, eevee-render-engine

I have a scene with many collection instances of a collection containing a car and its wheels. The car has a material on it with its base color being controlled by an object info node's random output:
[image]

Everything looks good as long as I am in material preview with the overlays turned off:
[image]

But with the overlays turned on(or sometimes the other way around) or if rendered using the EEVEE render engine, all the cars will have the same color.
[image]

It would be appreciated if anyone could suggest a solution to fix this problem(I don't want the colors to be controlled by position because the cars are animated) or report the bug(If this is a bug).

here is the .blend file:
https://mega.nz/file/4whyzTYK#LYLMOGpAT3VvUi4j73Jg63W2p8sG_HRQ8L3E_A107z0

Comment: There are no Blender developers here and no-one here has any association with the Blender Foundation so if you think you've found a bug you should report it via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu. Also see https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports

Comment: I don't know the exact steps to cause this problem which is needed in order to report a bug.

Comment: Well you've just described how to produce it in your question so I'd have thought that submitting that and your Blend file in your report should be sufficient.

Comment: maybe wanna try another Blender version? i tried on 4.0alpha and it worked: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFwNP.gif